# Docker Container exited with Error: /init.sh: not found

Tags: docker

After creating my image and build the containers, my web container give's me that Error:

none
/usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: 9: exec: /init.sh: not found

Thats my Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpq-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libwebp-dev \
        git \
        && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ \
        --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
        --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ \
        && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
        && docker-php-ext-install pdo \
        && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
        && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
        && docker-php-ext-install intl \
        && docker-php-ext-install zip \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Volume
VOLUME ["/var/www/html"]

# Clean Up
RUN apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /var/www/html/.git

# Init
COPY /init.sh /init.sh
RUN chmod +x /init.sh
CMD ["/init.sh"]
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the very very first line of `/init.sh` (it should be something like `#!/bin/sh`)?  Is it possible the file got added with DOS line endings?

Comment: @DavidMaze The first lines are `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: (I don't see in this Dockerfile where you `COPY` any PHP code into the image.  The `VOLUME` will cause a space leak and prevent some other Dockerfile commands from running and I'd remove it.  `RUN apt-get clean` on its own line won't actually free up any space; if you do need to run it then it should be in the same command as the `apt-get install`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze i addet the full Dockerfile.

Comment: @TheCallofDuty Have you figured out why the error message of failed to compute cache key: "/init.sh" not found: not found is shown? I am building a python container and I have the same error.

Comment: --- I changed #!/bin/bash to #/bin/sh and it is now working.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone else stumbling upon this.

If you build a Linux image on a Windows machine, make sure, that the *init.sh* file uses **CR** (Carriage return) and not the windows default **CRLF** (Carriage return Line Feed) for controlling when a line ends.

---

How you do that may vary depending on the development environment you are using.

**VSCode/VSCodium**

Just look in the bottom right corner. If you click on it, you can select which Control character should be used for line endings.

[image: VSCode/VSCodium CRchange]

**Notepad++**

Bottom Right Corner. You have to right click on it.

[image]